# Rails create two associatiated models in one New-Create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I have such models:

```
class Doc
  has_many :photos
end
```

and

```
class Photo
  belongs_to :doc
end
```

all photos uploaded to the cloud with CarrierWave-Paperclip like approach.

DocController#new prebuilds Doc with:

```
@doc = Doc.new
```

And only after saving this new Doc, in update action i can really upload photos to existed Doc object with:

```
@doc.photos << some_new_photo
```

But i want this feature in doc#new action. So, how i can upload photos like prebuilded Photo objects and add them to prebuilded Doc with @doc.photos << [photos] at the same time?

UPD:

Main problem, that when i make doc#new - i don't really know how many photos i'll upload during using form. So i have dynamically builded array of photos, that shouldn't be saved to DB, if associated Doc not saved/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a somewhat convoluted Rails feature called [accepts_nested_attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) which lets you create any number of associated objects in one go.

Basically your create call would end up accepting something like this:

```
{ :doc => { :name => 'somname', :date => Time.now, :photos_attributes => [
    { :filename => 'funnybear.gif', :filesize => '120kb' },
    { :filename => 'happybear.gif', :filesize => '72kb'  },
    { :filename => 'angrybear.gif', :filesize => '240kb' }
  ]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use blocks

```
@doc = Doc.new do |doc|
  doc.photos << some_new_photo
end
```

or you can redefine initialize method

```
class Doc
 def initialize
   @photos << some_new_photos
 end
end
```

Comment: Don't ever re-define the `initialize` method in an AR class without calling `super` as well. By doing it this way you've lost any functionality that AR provides through its own `initialize` method.

Comment: Oh, yeah! I'm sorry I just forgot to add super method you are right. I thought it's simple class objects, but when see the "belongs_to" and "has_many" I understood my fault.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use build:

```
@doc = Doc.new
params[:photos].each do |some_new_photo|
   @doc.photos.build some_new_photo
end
if @doc.save! 
   ... etc
```